# Elasticsearch fuzzyness doesn't always match

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, fuzzy-search

We use elasticsearch as for both globalsearch and quicksearch, with a generic configuration.

The globalsearch is able to search for multiple types, while the quicksearch will only look for one type (this is used by a generic component).

One of the types quicksearch is supposed to search for is called `workorder`. I have several workorders, two of them are stored like this:

```
{
    "_source": {
        "name": "70187"
    }
}

{
    "_source": {
        "name": "60255"
    }
}
```

However, I am getting some unexpected behavior from fuzzyness:

- When I search for `6025`, it can match `60255`.
- When I search for `7018`, it is **not** able to match `70187`

I use this configuration:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "multi_match": {
                        "fields": [
                            "name",
                            "last_name",
                            "first_name"
                        ],
                        "fuzziness": 1,
                        "max_expansions": 1,
                        "query": 6025,
                        "type": "most_fields"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "multi_match": {
                        "fields": [
                            "name",
                            "last_name",
                            "first_name"
                        ],
                        "max_expansions": 1,
                        "query": 6025,
                        "type": "most_fields"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "multi_match": {
                        "fields": [
                            "content",
                            "description"
                        ],
                        "max_expansions": 1,
                        "query": 6025,
                        "slop": 5,
                        "type": "best_fields"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "multi_match": {
                        "boost": 15,
                        "fields": [
                            "_id",
                            "reference",
                            "mobilenumber",
                            "phonenumber",
                            "batchnumber",
                            "number"
                        ],
                        "max_expansions": 1,
                        "query": 6025,
                        "type": "best_fields"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Why is it doing this? How can I fix it?

## EDIT(1)

I forgot to mention that I am running ElasticSearch 5.6.

## EDIT(2)

Apparently with just the two records I mentioned, I was able to find both workorders just fine. I deleted the index I was using.

After adding another two of my existing workorders, I was able to reproduce the problem with just four records.

The two added records are:

```
{
    "name" : "70186"
}

{
    "name" : "68012"
}
```

In case it is important, the IDs of these four records are:

- 70186: 9
- 70187: 10
- 60255: 11
- 68012: 12

## EDIT(3)

Steps to reproduce: https://gist.github.com/DevMcC/fe890dcbcba806da8086c4811a0db776

Comment: I reproduced your case and was able to find `70187` by searching for `7018`. Feel free to gist an exact recreation of your problem so we can investigate further.

Comment: Ahh, that's a bummer. I uhh, failed to mention that I am running ElasticSearch 5.6, are still able to find `70187` while on that version? (I'll update my question to include the version I am running)

Comment: Yes, I'm able to on 5.6.2

Comment: Hey @Val I see edit #2 :D?

Comment: Nope, I can find both records `70186` and `70187` by searching for `7018`. Again, please provide exact recreations steps so that we can compare apples to apples

Comment: Use Kibana discovery section to reproduce your query and make the necessary fix.

Comment: Hey @Val, I've made a gist so we can compare them apples.

Comment: The first command doesn't delete the index, but only document with id = 9. Deleting the index can be done with `curl -X DELETE "localhost:9200/apples`

Comment: Oops, sorry... pasted the wrong url in there, I've updated the gist.

Comment: Hey @Val, I know it's now almost 10 days since the last reply on this question, but did you happen to have the time to check if you could reproduce the issue through the gist I linked?

Answer (score 0):

In Elasticsearch fuzziness you should pass parameter

```
 "prefix_length":1 // 0,1,2...
```

Number of beginning characters left unchanged when creating expansions. Defaults to 0.

the fuzzy query creates a set of all possible variations, or expansions, of the search term within a specified edit distance.

In your case -

```
"fuzziness": 1,
```

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "fuzzy": {
      "user.id": {
        "value": "ki",
        "fuzziness": "AUTO",
        "max_expansions": 50,
        "prefix_length": 0,
        "transpositions": true,
        "rewrite": "constant_score"
      }
    }
  }
}
```